# Including local jar file in project at build time using gradle

Tags: java, salesforce, gradle

I want to include enterprise.jar file of salesforce in my project at build time using gradle
Could anyone help me out how to include a local jar file that exists in src/main/resources folder in my project.

Comment: Hi, I guess you might be interested in reading http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Possible-to-specify-my-own-classpath-entries-td1433673.html 
Hope this helps

Comment: I just want to add the jar file in build path of project using gradle. This link doesn't provide any such info. Could you please provide further pointers.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This is explained in [the documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sub:file_dependencies). The following should do:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('./src/main/resources/enterprise.jar')
}
```

I wouldn't put the jar in `src/main/resources` though. It's not a resource of your project, but a compile dependency. I would put it in a lib directory.

Comment: How can I add a jar of source to get the documentation in my IDE.

Comment: i added a third party jar using the same syntax mentioned above -->  compile files('libs/ojdbc6-11.1.0.jar') . But when war file is built I don't see this jar inside it (WEB-INF\lib) . How do i make sure local jar is present inside the war?