# How do i include external .jar in my gradle java project?

Tags: java, gradle-plugin, rundeck

I have a .jar file on my desktop and I would like to add it as a dependency on my project to use the existing methods on it. how do I do that?

Comment: Perhaps this post could help you [Including local jar file in project at build time using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12576972/11012656)

Comment: I had already seen these posts and tested but it didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is gradle.
Write code in jar method of build.gradle

```
configurations.compile.forEach {
    zipTree(it)
}
println list
from list
with jar
```

Comment: this didn't works :/

Comment: jar{
configurations.compile.forEach {
    zipTree(it)
}
println list
from list
with jar
}